# How games get configured to run on wine

Tags: wine

Using Wine via PlayOnLinux I'm now having the curiosity to understand HOW a game running on Windows gets configured to run on ubuntu under Wine.

Answer (score 1):

PlayOnLinux uses scripts to install Windows games onto your computer and get them running through Wine. The scripts download and install various Windows-specific libraries that your games might need and gets your game to be run by a certain Wine version - normally one that the script author knows works with the game - and certain Wine settings (such as whether the Wine runs in 'Windows XP' mode or 'Windows 7' mode).

The game installed with the specific libraries and Wine version are put into a 'Wineprefix' which is a certain folder on your computer which runs programs with those libraries and Wine version. These are located at `~/.playonlinux/wineprefix`.

Of course, understanding how Wine itself works is a different question altogether. You can learn more about Wine itself [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29).

Sources: 
Own knowledge 
[PlayOnLinux Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayOnLinux)